# A simple C++ function with different answers on different computers

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

Consider the code below which is basically gamma function in C++:

```
 double myGamma(double x){
 return gamma(x);
}
```

When I run the code on Mac OS 10.7.5, it works perfectly fine. However, when I run it on a unix server, it returns strange result. Does anyone know what the issue is? Is gamma() function different under linux system?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think C++ is what you think it is. You also didn't bother to tell us what the output actually was, and why you think one of them is "wrong". What is "the latest Rcpp"? SO is a question archive so that statement could become wrong very quickly. Specify all your version numbers. And, if you can, abstract RCPP out of this entirely.

Comment: -1 "the code below which is basically gamma function in C++" is not even C++

Comment: That's not c++ code for sure?!? ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Rcpp is a glue package which makes it easy to get to C++ from R and back, with whole object and what have you; see the tag.  But it is an innocent bystander here as you and other note.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag so that people don't get confused.

Comment: Remove the Rcpp tag instead. Write a three-line standalone C++ program, compile and link it on both systems. Compare the result. Hint: You're not getting `gamma()` from R. And the answer you got seems correct to me.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I just did. I should've thought more on how to ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bried look in my gamma function, as defined in linux manual give me the following results:

> [...] These functions are deprecated: instead, use either the tgamma(3) or the lgamma(3) functions, as appropriate. [...]
>
> [...] Because of historical variations in behavior across systems, this function is not specified in any standard. [...]

Comment: This is the solution, @Tomas Badan. Would you be able to guide me how you figured that out? Is there any place that I can check which functions are different in linux ?